# Remove tabs from media uploader for a CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, uploads, tabs

I use the media uploader in a own meta-box for a custom post type called "premium".
The Thickbox opens after a click of the button in the meta-box and files can be uploaded.

Now I want to remove the tabs "From URL" and "Library" only when used the uploader in the edit/new-page for the CPT or if possible with the call of the click-event.

I have no idea how to resolve.

P.S.:
I use this js for calling the thickbox and tried to remove a tab via jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#pc_extContent_button').click(function() {
    formfield = jQuery('#pc_extContent').attr('name');
    tbframe_interval = setInterval(function() {
        jQuery('#tab-type_url').hide();
    }, 2000);
    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=file&TB_iframe=true')
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `media_upload_tabs filter` check for your post type and unset any tab you don't want ex:

```
function remove_media_library_tab($tabs) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['post_id'])) {
        $post_type = get_post_type($_REQUEST['post_id']);
        if ('premium' == $post_type)
            unset($tabs['library']);
            unset($tabs['type_url']);
    }
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter('media_upload_tabs', 'remove_media_library_tab');
```

Comment: Thanks for the starting point. But it doesn't work, if you call the thickbox, via a js like mentioned in my question. So I ended up with the solution I quote in the following answer.

Answer (score 1):

First it is necessar to change the JavaScript for including the post_id in the request:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#pc_extContent_button').click(function() {
        var pID = jQuery('#post_ID').val();
        formfield = jQuery('#pc_extContent').attr('name');
        tb_show('premiumTB', 'media-upload.php?post_id='+ pID +'&type=image&TB_iframe=true');
        return false;
    });
    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        imgurl = jQuery('img', html).attr('href');
        jQuery('#pc_extContent').val(imgurl);
        tb_remove();
    }
});
```

Then the solution of Bainternet can be used in the functions.php (or similar)

```
function remove_media_library_tab($tabs) {
  if (isset($_REQUEST['post_id'])) {
    $post_type = get_post_type($_REQUEST['post_id']);
    if ('premium' == $post_type) {
      unset($tabs['library']);
      unset($tabs['type_url']);
    }
  }
  return $tabs;
}
add_filter('media_upload_tabs', 'remove_media_library_tab');
```

So all works fine together and the tabs are removed.