# Looking for a hook to add attachment information to the media library tab

Tags: wp-admin, filters, media-library, actions, attachment-fields-to-edit

I would like to be able to determine if an image has been attached to a post by looking at the collapsed viewmedia library tab. Is there's a hook I can use to add that data to this view of the Media Libray tab?

I've included a mock-up of what I'd like the media library to look like.

[image]

Is it possible to amend the current media library tab or would I have to create a custom tab to get this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, and I've researched the topic a [lot](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51165/12615), there's no hook to do this. Neither an easy jQuery.

And looking at WordPress 3.5 beta-1, all previous hacks and hooks may be obsolete soon or just after soon... 
[image: wordpress 3.5 beta]