# How to remove a tab in Media Upload page in wordpress

Tags: uploads, media-library

I use wp_enqueue_script('media-upload') show upload box,but i don't want show "Media Library"
I use upload for frontend and don't want remove it on backend.
Can you help me modify it
Thanks

I fixed this problem

```
if(current_user_can('subscriber')){
    function remove_media_library_tab($tabs) {
            unset($tabs['library']);
        //    unset($tabs['type_url']);

        return $tabs;
    }
    add_filter('media_upload_tabs', 'remove_media_library_tab');
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46808/remove-tabs-from-media-uploader-for-a-cpt

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it has to do with enqueueing, if all you want to do is hide the Media Library tab in the media upload window.

I found the [following solutio](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/hide-media-upload-library-tabs-leave-url-tab)n (haven't tried it myself):

```
function remove_media_library_tab($tabs) {
     unset($tabs['library']);
     return $tabs;
}
add_filter('media_upload_tabs', 'remove_media_library_tab');
```

The link contains some more details as to *why* this is what needs to be done